# React-native share on discord

Tags: react-native, discord, share, deep-linking

I'm implementing a feature on a project where we want users to be able to share a post on discord. Implementing sharing on facebook or twitter was easy using https://react-native-community.github.io/react-native-share/docs/share-single

But there's no support for discord on shareSingle and I don't want a share button calling for Native Share menu which could link to discord, I want a discord icon redirecting directly to discord. But I can't even find a way to open discord app with url schemas or universal link to trigger the app (discord:// or discord://discord or discordapp:// ...).

I tried to find a way to get access to native sharing in order to open discord sharing singly, but couldn't find a way.

Does anyone implemented discord sharing and have any tips on how to achieve that in react-native ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a fork the project and add this files:

*android/src/main/java/cl/json/social/DiscordShare.java*

```java
package cl.json.social;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import java.io.File;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.net.Uri;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap;


public class DiscordShare extends SingleShareIntent {

    private static final String PACKAGE = "com.discord";
    private static final String PLAY_STORE_LINK = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.discord";

    public DiscordShare(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void open(ReadableMap options) throws ActivityNotFoundException {
        super.open(options);
        //  extra params here
        this.openIntentChooser();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getPackage() {
        return PACKAGE;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDefaultWebLink() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getPlayStoreLink() {
        return PLAY_STORE_LINK;
    }
}
```

Edit *android/src/main/java/cl/json/RNShareModule.java*

```java
package cl.json;
// ...

import cl.json.social.DiscordShare;
public class RNShareModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements ActivityEventListener {
 // ...
private enum SHARES {
        facebook,
        generic,
        pagesmanager,
        twitter,
        whatsapp,
        instagram,
        instagramstories,
        googleplus,
        email,
        pinterest,
        messenger,
        snapchat,
        sms,
        linkedin,
        discord; // ADDED


        public static ShareIntent getShareClass(String social, ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
            SHARES share = valueOf(social);
            switch (share) {
                case generic:
                    return new GenericShare(reactContext);
                case facebook:
                    return new FacebookShare(reactContext);
                case pagesmanager:
                    return new FacebookPagesManagerShare(reactContext);
                case twitter:
                    return new TwitterShare(reactContext);
                case whatsapp:
                    return new WhatsAppShare(reactContext);
                case instagram:
                    return new InstagramShare(reactContext);
                case instagramstories:
                    return new InstagramStoriesShare(reactContext);
                case googleplus:
                    return new GooglePlusShare(reactContext);
                case email:
                    return new EmailShare(reactContext);
                case pinterest:
                    return new PinterestShare(reactContext);
                case sms:
                    return new SMSShare(reactContext);
                case snapchat:
                    return new SnapChatShare(reactContext);
                case messenger:
                    return new MessengerShare(reactContext);
                case linkedin:
                    return new LinkedinShare(reactContext);
                case discord:
                    return new DiscordShare(reactContext); // ADDED
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
    };

}
// ...
```

Finally edit *index.js*

```js
//...
class RNShare {
//...
static Social = {
    FACEBOOK: NativeModules.RNShare.FACEBOOK || 'facebook',
    FACEBOOK_STORIES: NativeModules.RNShare.FACEBOOK_STORIES || 'facebook-stories',
    PAGESMANAGER: NativeModules.RNShare.PAGESMANAGER || 'pagesmanager',
    TWITTER: NativeModules.RNShare.TWITTER || 'twitter',
    WHATSAPP: NativeModules.RNShare.WHATSAPP || 'whatsapp',
    INSTAGRAM: NativeModules.RNShare.INSTAGRAM || 'instagram',
    INSTAGRAM_STORIES: NativeModules.RNShare.INSTAGRAM_STORIES || 'instagramstories',
    GOOGLEPLUS: NativeModules.RNShare.GOOGLEPLUS || 'googleplus',
    EMAIL: NativeModules.RNShare.EMAIL || 'email',
    PINTEREST: NativeModules.RNShare.PINTEREST || 'pinterest',
    LINKEDIN: NativeModules.RNShare.LINKEDIN || 'linkedin',
    SMS: NativeModules.RNShare.SMS || 'sms',
    DISCORD: NativeModules.RNShare.DISCORD || 'discord', // ADDED
  };
// ...
}
```

In your project use:

```js
    Share.shareSingle({
      title: 'test',
      message: 'hola mundo',
      url: 'https://json.cl',
      social: Share.Social.DISCORD,
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        err && console.log(err);
      });
```

Result:

[image: Result Discord Share]

Comment: Thanks for the idea, any idea for iOS as I need both ?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the IOS code as follows:
node_modules/react-native-share/ios/DiscordShare.m

```
#import "DiscordShare.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
@import Photos;

@implementation DiscordShare
    RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();
- (void)shareSingle:(NSDictionary *)options
    failureCallback:(RCTResponseErrorBlock)failureCallback
    successCallback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)successCallback {
    
    NSString *text = [RCTConvert NSString:options[@"message"]];
    text = (NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,(CFStringRef) text, NULL,CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]"),kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
    
    NSString *url = [RCTConvert NSString:options[@"url"]];
    
    NSString *discordMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"discord://message?text=%@", text];
    NSString *discordMsgUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"discord://message?text=%@&url%@", text, url];

    NSString * urlDiscord = url ? discordMsgUrl : discordMsg;
    
    NSURL * shareURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlDiscord];
    
    
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: shareURL]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: shareURL];
        successCallback(@[@true, @""]);
    } else {
        // Cannot open discord
        NSString *stringURL = @"https://apps.apple.com/us/app/discord-chat-talk-hangout/id985746746";
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
        
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {}];
        
        NSString *errorMessage = @"Not installed";
        NSDictionary *userInfo = @{NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey: NSLocalizedString(errorMessage, nil)};
        NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"com.rnshare" code:1 userInfo:userInfo];
        
        NSLog(@"%@", errorMessage);
        failureCallback(error);
    }
}

@end
```

node_modules/react-native-share/ios/DiscordShare.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
// import RCTConvert
#import <React/RCTConvert.h>
// import RCTBridge
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
// import RCTUIManager
#import <React/RCTUIManager.h>
// import RCTLog
#import <React/RCTLog.h>
// import RCTUtils
#import <React/RCTUtils.h>
@interface DiscordShare : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>

- (void) shareSingle:(NSDictionary *)options failureCallback:(RCTResponseErrorBlock)failureCallback successCallback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)successCallback;

@end
```

node_modules/react-native-share/ios/RNShare.m

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import "RNShare.h"
// import RCTConvert
#import <React/RCTConvert.h>
// import RCTLog
#import <React/RCTLog.h>
// import RCTUtils
#import <React/RCTUtils.h>
// import RCTBridge
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
// import RCTBridge
#import <React/RCTUIManager.h>
#import "GenericShare.h"
#import "WhatsAppShare.h"
#import "InstagramShare.h"
#import "DiscordShare.h"        // ADD LINE
#import "InstagramStories.h"
#import "FacebookStories.h"
#import "GooglePlusShare.h"
#import "EmailShare.h"
.....

@implementation RNShare

RCTResponseErrorBlock rejectBlock;
RCTResponseSenderBlock resolveBlock;

// we need this since this controller
// may implement a delegate and could be garbage collected
// before it is called
EmailShare *shareCtl;

- (dispatch_queue_t)methodQueue
{
    return dispatch_get_main_queue();
}

+ (BOOL)requiresMainQueueSetup
{
    return YES;
}

- (id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        shareCtl = [[EmailShare alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (CGRect)sourceRectInView:(UIView *)sourceView
             anchorViewTag:(NSNumber *)anchorViewTag
{
    if (anchorViewTag) {
        UIView *anchorView = [self.bridge.uiManager viewForReactTag:anchorViewTag];
        return [anchorView convertRect:anchorView.bounds toView:sourceView];
    } else {
        return (CGRect){sourceView.center, {1, 1}};
    }
}

- (BOOL)isImageMimeType:(NSString *)data {
    NSRange range = [data rangeOfString:@"data:image" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if (data && range.location != NSNotFound) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

- (NSDictionary *)constantsToExport
{
  return @{
    @"FACEBOOK": @"facebook",
    @"FACEBOOKSTORIES": @"facebookstories",
    @"TWITTER": @"twitter",
    @"GOOGLEPLUS": @"googleplus",
    @"WHATSAPP": @"whatsapp",
    @"INSTAGRAM": @"instagram",
    @"INSTAGRAMSTORIES": @"instagramstories",
    @"TELEGRAM": @"telegram",
    @"EMAIL": @"email",
    @"MESSENGER": @"messanger",
    @"VIBER": @"viber",
    @"DISCORD": @"discord",    // ADD LINE

    @"SHARE_BACKGROUND_IMAGE": @"shareBackgroundImage",
    @"SHARE_BACKGROUND_VIDEO": @"shareBackgroundVideo",
    @"SHARE_STICKER_IMAGE": @"shareStickerImage",
    @"SHARE_BACKGROUND_AND_STICKER_IMAGE": @"shareBackgroundAndStickerImage",
  };
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(shareSingle:(NSDictionary *)options
                  failureCallback:(RCTResponseErrorBlock)failureCallback
                  successCallback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)successCallback)
{
    NSString *social = [RCTConvert NSString:options[@"social"]];
    if (social) {
        NSLog(@"%@", social);
        if([social isEqualToString:@"facebook"]) {
            NSLog(@"TRY OPEN FACEBOOK");
            GenericShare *shareCtl = [[GenericShare alloc] init];
            [shareCtl shareSingle:options failureCallback: failureCallback successCallback: successCallback serviceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook inAppBaseUrl:@"fb://"];
        } else if([social isEqualToString:@"facebookstories"]) {
            NSString *appId = [RCTConvert NSString:options[@"appId"]];
            if (appId) {
                NSLog(@"TRY OPEN FACEBOOK STORIES");
                FacebookStories *shareCtl = [[FacebookStories alloc] init];
                [shareCtl shareSingle:options failureCallback: failureCallback successCallback: successCallback];
            } else {
                RCTLogError(@"key 'appId' missing in options");
                return;
            }
        } else if([social isEqualToString:@"twitter"]) {
            NSLog(@"TRY OPEN Twitter");
            GenericShare *shareCtl = [[GenericShare alloc] init];
            [shareCtl shareSingle:options failureCallback: failureCallback successCallback: successCallback serviceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter inAppBaseUrl:@"twitter://"];
        } else if([social isEqualToString:@"googleplus"]) {
            NSLog(@"TRY OPEN google plus");
            GooglePlusShare *shareCtl = [[GooglePlusShare alloc] init];
            [shareCtl shareSingle:options failureCallback: failureCallback successCallback: successCallback];
        } else if([social isEqualToString:@"whatsapp"]) {
            NSLog(@"TRY OPEN whatsapp");
            WhatsAppShare *shareCtl = [[WhatsAppShare alloc] init];
            [shareCtl shareSingle:options failureCallback: failureCallback successCallback: successCallback];
        } else if([social isEqualToString:@"instagram"]) {
            NSLog(@"TRY OPEN instagram");
            InstagramShare *shareCtl = [[InstagramShare alloc] init];
            if([self isImageMimeType:options[@"url"]]) {// Condition to handle image
                [shareCtl shareSingleImage:options failureCallback: failureCallback successCallback: successCallback];
            } else {
                [shareCtl shareSingle:options failureCallback: failureCallback successCallback: successCallback];
            }
        } else if([social isEqualToString:@"instagramstories"]) {
            NSLog(@"TRY OPEN instagram-stories");
            InstagramStories *shareCtl = [[InstagramStories alloc] init];
            [shareCtl shareSingle:options failureCallback: failureCallback successCallback: successCallback];
         } else if([social isEqualToString:@"telegram"]) {
            NSLog(@"TRY OPEN telegram");
            TelegramShare *shareCtl = [[TelegramShare alloc] init];
            [shareCtl shareSingle:options failureCallback: failureCallback successCallback: successCallback];
        } else if([social isEqualToString:@"email"]) {
            NSLog(@"TRY OPEN email");
            [shareCtl shareSingle:options failureCallback: failureCallback successCallback: successCallback];
        } else if([social isEqualToString:@"viber"]) {
            NSLog(@"TRY OPEN viber");
            ViberShare *shareCtl = [[ViberShare alloc] init];
            [shareCtl shareSingle:options failureCallback: failureCallback successCallback: successCallback];
        } else if([social isEqualToString:@"discord"]) {
            NSLog(@"TRY OPEN discord");
            // ADD NEXT LINE
            DiscordShare *shareCtl = [[DiscordShare alloc] init];
            [shareCtl shareSingle:options failureCallback: failureCallback successCallback: successCallback];
        } else if([social isEqualToString:@"messenger"]) {
            NSLog(@"TRY OPEN messenger");
            MessengerShare *shareCtl = [[MessengerShare alloc] init];
            [shareCtl shareSingle:options failureCallback: failureCallback successCallback: successCallback];
        }
    } else {
        RCTLogError(@"key 'social' missing in options");
        return;
    }
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(open:(NSDictionary *)options
                  failureCallback:(RCTResponseErrorBlock)failureCallback
                  successCallback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)successCallback)
{
    if (RCTRunningInAppExtension()) {
        RCTLogError(@"Unable to show action sheet from app extension");
        return;
    }

    NSMutableArray<id> *items = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSString *message = [RCTConvert NSString:options[@"message"]];
    if (message) {
        [items addObject:message];
    }
    BOOL saveToFiles = [RCTConvert BOOL:options[@"saveToFiles"]];
    NSArray *urlsArray = options[@"urls"];
    for (int i=0; i<urlsArray.count; i++) {
        NSURL *URL = [RCTConvert NSURL:urlsArray[i]];
        if (URL) {
            if ([URL.scheme.lowercaseString isEqualToString:@"data"]) {
                NSError *error;
                NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL
                                                     options:(NSDataReadingOptions)0
                                                       error:&error];
                if (!data) {
                    failureCallback(error);
                    return;
                }
                if (saveToFiles) {
                    NSURL *filePath = [RNShareUtils getPathFromBase64:URL.absoluteString with:data];
                    if (filePath) {
                        [items addObject: filePath];
                    }
                } else {
                    [items addObject:data];
                }
            } else {
                [items addObject:URL];
            }
        }
    }

    NSArray *activityItemSources = options[@"activityItemSources"];
    if (activityItemSources) {
        [activityItemSources enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
            RNShareActivityItemSource *activityItemSource = [[RNShareActivityItemSource alloc] initWithOptions:obj];
            [items addObject:activityItemSource];
        }];
    }

    if (items.count == 0) {
        RCTLogError(@"No `url` or `message` to share");
        return;
    }

    UIViewController *controller = RCTPresentedViewController();

    if (saveToFiles) {
        NSArray *urls = [items filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id  _Nullable evaluatedObject, NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nullable bindings) {
            return [evaluatedObject isKindOfClass:[NSURL class]];
        }]];

        if (urls.count == 0) {
            RCTLogError(@"No `urls` to save in Files");
            return;
        }
        if (@available(iOS 11.0, macCatalyst 13.1, *)) {
            resolveBlock = successCallback;
            rejectBlock = failureCallback;
            UIDocumentPickerViewController *documentPicker = nil;
            if (@available(iOS 15.0, macCatalyst 15.0, *)) {
                documentPicker = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initForExportingURLs:urls asCopy:YES];
            } else {
                documentPicker = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithURLs:urls inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeExportToService];
            }
            [documentPicker setDelegate:self];
            [controller presentViewController:documentPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
            return;
        }
    }

    UIActivityViewController *shareController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];

    NSString *subject = [RCTConvert NSString:options[@"subject"]];
    if (subject) {
        [shareController setValue:subject forKey:@"subject"];
    }

    NSArray *excludedActivityTypes = [RCTConvert NSStringArray:options[@"excludedActivityTypes"]];
    if (excludedActivityTypes) {
        shareController.excludedActivityTypes = excludedActivityTypes;
    }

    __weak UIActivityViewController* weakShareController = shareController;
    shareController.completionWithItemsHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, __unused NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError) {
        
        // always dismiss since this may be called from cancelled shares
        // but the share menu would remain open, and our callback would fire again on close
        if(weakShareController){
            // closing activity view controller
            [weakShareController dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
        } else {
            [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
        }

        
        if (activityError) {
            failureCallback(activityError);
        } else {
            successCallback(@[@(completed), RCTNullIfNil(activityType)]);
        }
        
        // clear the completion handler to prevent cycles
        if(weakShareController){
            weakShareController.completionWithItemsHandler = nil;
        }
    };

    shareController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    NSNumber *anchorViewTag = [RCTConvert NSNumber:options[@"anchor"]];
    if (!anchorViewTag) {
        shareController.popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = 0;
    }
    shareController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = controller.view;
    shareController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = [self sourceRectInView:controller.view anchorViewTag:anchorViewTag];

    [controller presentViewController:shareController animated:YES completion:nil];

    shareController.view.tintColor = [RCTConvert UIColor:options[@"tintColor"]];
}

- (void)documentPickerWasCancelled:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller {
    if (rejectBlock) {
        NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"CANCELLED" code: 500 userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:@"PICKER_WAS_CANCELLED"}];
        rejectBlock(error);
    }
}

- (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentsAtURLs:(NSArray<NSURL *> *)urls {
    if (resolveBlock) {
        resolveBlock(@[@(YES), @"com.apple.DocumentsApp"]);
    }
}

@end
```

node_modules/react-native-share/src/index.tsx

```
.....
const RNShare = {
     .......
     MESSENGER: NativeModules.RNShare.MESSENGER || Social.Messenger,
     SNAPCHAT: NativeModules.RNShare.SNAPCHAT || Social.Snapchat,
     VIBER: NativeModules.RNShare.VIBER || Social.Viber,
     DISCORD: NativeModules.RNShare.DISCORD || 'discord', // ADDED
   },
.....
```